# How to use BASH to output all shared top values

Tags: bash, shell-script

Data set is as follows

```
name score
a 10 
b 20 
c 5 
d 15 
e 20
```

aim to output all names with the largest score. If there are multiple names with a shared largest score, output all of them. If possible, use only grep, sort, cut, head.

Currently, I have `tail -n +2 sources.txt | sort -k 2,2nr | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | head -1` which only output one of the largest, not both `b` and `e`.

Desired output is

```
b
e
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'FNR == 1   { next };
       FNR == NR  { if ($2 > max) { max = $2 } ; next };
       $2  == max { print $1 }' sources.txt sources.txt
b
e
```

This awk one-liner reads the input file (`sources.txt`) **twice** (which is why it has to be specified twice on the command line).  The first time to find the largest value of the second field ($2) and store it in variable `max`, and the second time to print the first field ($1) when $2 is equal to `max`.

It uses two built-in awk variables.   `FNR` is always equal to the line number of the current file and `NR` is always equal to the current line number of all input (a cumulative total).  So, when `FNR == NR`, it is reading the first file and when `FNR != NR`, it is **not** reading the first file.  Note that this doesn't work correctly if any of the input files are empty as empty files are not counted at all (there are no lines in an empty file, so there's nothing to count).

It ignores the first line of input (the header line) both times with `FNR == 1 { next }`.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: @HanlinZhang  i simplified the script a little which should make it easier to understand what it's doing.     `awk` scripts are basically a series of *test conditions* and *actions* that are applied in turn to each line of the script's input....this is obviously a huge simplification and generalisation but it's essentially true.

Comment: you should let there the first version of the script. It is much more smart.

Comment: @DanieleGrassini I'm much more inclined to post scripts & explanations that are easy for novices to understand and learn from and adapt.   Using stuff that you don't understand is just cargo-cult magic, and I have no interest at all in contributing to that....there's already far too much cargo-culting going on.